# Export ASP.net data to MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, asp.net, database-design, relational-database

I'm working on redesigning a database for a client. The client's original database was set up using ASP.net. However, my redesign involves creating a MySQL database (MySQL'll meld much better with the redesigned website).

Is there a way to export the data from the ASP.net set up so that I can include it in the MySQL database?

Comment: ***ASP.Net*** is a front end technology like ***php***; it is not a persistent storage. There is nothing to import from ASP.Net to MySQL. Do you mean importing data from ***MS SQL*** to ***MySQL***?

Comment: @win, sorry, I'm pretty new to ASP.Net. The previous web developer gave me a zip file with a bunch of ASP files in it, so I'm just trying to get to the data. Yes, I think it would be a MS SQL to a MySQL conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the migration is from Microsoft SQL Server to MySQL, this might help

[Migrating from ms sql server to mysql using workbench migration wizard](http://mysqlworkbench.org/2012/07/migrating-from-ms-sql-server-to-mysql-using-workbench-migration-wizard/comment-page-1/)

Comment: If I have been given a zip folder with the ASP.net files in it, what would be the best way to get these to run locally so I can get Workbench to detect the database? I'm thinking I can put them in an XAMPP folder and have Workbench point to that, maybe?

Comment: ASP.net and the database is two different things. What you have to get is the connection string of your database (MS SQL, MySQL). You may find the MSSQL on web.config file of your ASP.net project and the MySQL you might have known. Use that connection string on the  migration software and it will do the migration of the database for you (the database migration not the whole ASP.Net project).

Comment: Gotcha. That makes sense. Thanks for your help!